# Cannot import js files in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, eclipse, import

I've been searching for answered questions in here but i couldn't find the suitable one for me. I have an issue when trying to import my javascript files in my html (I'm coding in Eclipse Mars 2.0). I'm using apache tiles for template creation and the project is (trying to be) built in Angularjs. Here i attach some code and screenshots.

My html looks like this, in this first case ${contexto} value is "home"

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <script src="js/${contexto}/${contexto}-app.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/${contexto}/${contexto}-service.js"></script> 

    </head>

    <body>

            <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />

    </body>
</html>
```

My project is structured this way
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqNyu.png)

And the error I'm getting when deploying it is this one: 
[chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbYwv.png)

Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT** I think the problem is related with the servlet configuration... if I comment the servlet config in my web.xml I can access the localhost:8080/web/js/home/home-app.js file and i have the "Hello world" form index.htm but cannot access to localhost:8080/web/home. On the other hand if i discomment them,  i cannot access the js files but i can access localhost:8080/web/home. Here is my web.xml if it helps...

```
   ...

    <!-- ==============Spring============= -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

     <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>webapp.web</param-value>
    </context-param>

    </web-app>
```

**SOLUTION** I could solve the issue, defining the resources in the jsp as spring resources instead of the conventional ... tag.

Comment: You forgot the `views` directory

Comment: @Ben Harold - So it'll end up being <script src="js/${contexto}/views/${contexto}-app.js"></script> for example?

Comment: My mistake. That directory is on the same level as your JS files. At any rate, you'll want the URL that is included in your `script` tag to be accessible from your browser. For example: `http://localhost:8080/home/js/home/home-app.js` should be available from your browser.

Comment: Hi, @Ben Harold, you are right... i cannot access the js files from the localhost:8080/web/js/home/... .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `script` tags are attempting to access a file that does not exist according to your web server. The `js/home/home-app.js` and `js/home/home-service.js` portions of the URLs appear to be correct based on the screenshot of your file structure, so the issue is before that.

- Is this project in the document root or is there a subdirectory where it resides?
- What happens if you add a slash before `js`?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse Me,I advice you Look this demo about Dlobal:

- https://gist.github.com/complone/bce3c7c30fb7dc37900c67f78ae61f30

But

- I think this Global variable  exist error when executed,js File not call in .html